# Issues with react beautiful dnd when mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having error like this with `react-beautiful-dnd`

[image]

Here is my following code in `App.js`:

```
const getComponentsFromSearchQuery = (query) => {
  // if there's no query, you probably want all the components
  if (!query) return Object.values(planets);

  const filter = query.split(",").map((v) => v.trim());

  return (
    Object.entries(planets)
      // get all planets that match the search query
      .filter(([k]) => filter.some((f) => k.indexOf(f) !== -1))
      // return just the component
      .map(([k, v]) => v)
  );
};

function App() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [generateClick, setGenerateClick] = useState(false);
  const [components, setComponents] = useState(
    getComponentsFromSearchQuery("")
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    setComponents(getComponentsFromSearchQuery(searchQuery));
    setGenerateClick(true);
  };
 return (
      <DragDropContext>
        <Droppable droppableId="planets">
          {(provided) => (
            <ul {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
              {components.map(({ id, C }, index) => {
                return (
                  <Draggable key={index} draggableId={id} index={index}>
                    {(provided) => (
                      <div
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                      >
                        <C />
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                );
              })}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </ul>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
     );
}

export default App;
```

If I change the value "C" to "name" it will work but I am trying to loop through components so I need the letter to be uppercase but it keep getting me error.

How can I fix this error?

Updated components:

```
const Earth = () => {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 h-32 border border-gray-200 my-4">
      <div className="relative">
        <img
          className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-32 object-cover"
          src={earth}
          alt="earth"
        />
      </div>
      <p className="text-3xl font-bold text-left p-10">Earth</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Earth;
```

other components is just the same but different name and image.

Comment: Can you post the structure of an item in the `components` array?

Comment: Yes one sec. I will update that

Comment: @Pavindu just updated the code